# mongodb replicaset host name change error

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb replicaset on ubuntu.. In replica set, hosts are defined as localhost. You can see ;

```
{
    "_id" : "myrep",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "localhost:27017"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "localhost:27018"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "localhost:27019",
                    "priority" : 0
            }
    ]
```

}

I want to change host adresses with real ip of server. But when i run rs.reconfig, I get error :

```
{
    "assertion" : "hosts cannot switch between localhost and hostname",
    "assertionCode" : 13645,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
```

}

How can i solve it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to change host names is recreating replica set.. To make it right db directories need to be cleaned.. Then starting all servers with replication mode after that creating new repset with new host names fixed it.

Answer (score 24):

There is a cleaner way to do this:

```
use local
cfg = db.system.replset.findOne({_id:"replicaSetName"})
cfg.members[0].host="newHost:27017"
db.system.replset.update({_id:"replicaSetName"},cfg)
```

then restart mongo

Comment: This works - you MUST restart mongod afterwards, to ensure the new host setting is picked up. When successful, "rs.status()" will return the correct host name for each member.

Comment: This gets around the error changing the hosts, but I found I also had to execute cfg = rs.conf(); rs.reconfig(cfg); after the restart to make this stick.

Comment: I would like to add that `newHost`, if you re trying to deploy in the same machine, has to be the local network address of it, i.e. something like `192.168...` or `10.0...`

Comment: This was absolutely horrific.  Just wanted to debug transactions locally.  After about 6 hours of misery I find I had to start mongod with the --bind 0.0.0.0 parameter and then use your solution and set the replica set's host to IP to 192.168.1. . .  Is there a way to automate this setup without having to manually set the replica set's host like this?