# exception: hosts cannot switch between localhost and hostname

Tags: mongodb

I created a replication set. 
I added `localhost` in the set in the beginning, but when I try to edit the member with the actual hostname. I get error "exception: hosts cannot switch between localhost and hostname"

I need to get rid of localhost:27017 because, otherwise, it doesn't let me enter any other member as hostname (i.e. non-localhost address)

```
my-rs0:PRIMARY> cfg=rs.conf();
{
    "_id" : "my-rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:27017"
        }
    ]
}
my-rs0:PRIMARY> cfg.members[0].host="my-server04:27017"

my-rs0:PRIMARY> cfg
{
    "_id" : "my-rs0",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "my-server04:27017"
        }
    ]
}
```

**using rs.reconfig(cfg);**

```
my-rs0:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(cfg);
        {
            "errmsg" : "exception: hosts cannot switch between localhost and hostname",
            "code" : 13645,
            "ok" : 0
        }
```

**no luck with rs.add("my-server04:27017") or rs.remove("localhost:27017") as well.**

```
 my-rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("my-server04:27017");
    {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't use localhost in repl set member names except when using it for all members",
        "code" : 13393,
        "ok" : 0
    }
```

I have tried all the reconfiguration methods mentioned here [Replica Set Reconfig steps](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#replica-set-reconfiguration-usage)
But, none fixing above issue. Already spent hours, I am really frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to scrap your replicaset and start over.

I believe that when you initiated your Replica Set, you explicitly passed it a config document that references your MongoDB instance using localhost.

As I was investigating this, I brought up a replica set. When I initiated the replica set using `rs.initiate()` (without passing a config document) it used host name by default.

```
rs.initiate()

rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "stack1",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "MY-HOSTNAME:28001"
        }
    ]
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954535/mongodb-replicaset-host-name-change-error) describes the need to complete clear out your database files to create a fresh replica set.

Once I did this, I initiated a new replica set in the by passing a configuration document:

```
cfg = {
    "_id" : "stack1",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:28001"
        }
    ]
} 

rs.initiate(cfg)

rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "stack1",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:28001"
        }
    ]
}
```

Long story short, you'll need to delete all of the files in your `--dbpath` directory and re-create the replica set, without explicitly specifying "localhost" as your hostname.

Comment: Thanks for info, I deleted entire db and recreated with new replication set settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fixed it without dropping any database. Just edited the host field of the member in the local.system.replset collection to match the local ip and then restarted mongod. Everything worked perfect.

Comment: This solution works great if you do not want to delete the replica set (as in doing a restore outlined in this article: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/)

Answer (score 1):

I did according to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/#change-all-hostnames-at-the-same-time):

1. Restarted MongDB on another port (e.g. 37107) to prevent user connections to it.
2. Then started a shell on it:

```sh
$ mongo --port 37017
```

3. Then updated the configuration:

```js
use local
cfg = db.system.replset.findOne( { "_id": "my-rs0" } )
cfg.members[0].host = "my-server04:27017"
db.system.replset.update( { "_id": "my-rs0" } , cfg )
```

4. Then restarted MongoDB on the original port.